# how many '1' in a 32-bits integer programmed with python

Tags: python, c++, bit-manipulation

I have succeeded ran the code in C++,with the code below:

```
int countOnes(int num) {
    int count =0;
    while (num) {
        count ++;
        num = num & (num-1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

but it didn't work in Python version:

```
def countOnes(num):
    count = 0
    while(num):
        count += 1
        num = num&(num-1)
    return count
```

It seems blocked when the num = -1(0Xffffffff), why does it work in C++, but not in python？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this function works differently in the two languages is that they have different fundamental number types. In C++, `int` is indeed often a 32 bit integer in two's complement representation, though the language standard allows other representations. In Python, however, the standard number type has arbitrary precision.

The continuation criterion for your loop is that `num` is non-zero. If it doesn't terminate, let's add some debugging to see what happens instead:

```
def countOnes(num):
    count = 0
    while(num):
        count += 1
        num = num&(num-1)
        print(num) # <-- inspect what happens to num
    return count
```

Let's see what we get for different inputs:

```
>>> countOnes(1)
0
1
>>> countOnes(7)
6
4
0
3
```

For `-1`, however, things quickly go out of hand:

```
>>> countOnes(-1)
-2
-4
-8
-16
-32
-64
-128
-256
-512
-1024
-2048
-4096
...
```

`num` keeps decreasing. Since the number type has arbitrary size, the number will only keep growing more negative.

To simulate the fixed precision of the C integer, you can limit `num` to 32 bits:

```
def countOnes(num):
    num = num & 0xffffffff # <-- Limit num to 32 bits
    count = 0
    while(num):
        count += 1
        num = num&(num-1)
    return count
```

With debugging output, the output for `countOnes(-1)` is now:

```
>>> countOnes(-1)                         
4294967294
4294967292
4294967288
4294967280
4294967264
4294967232
4294967168
4294967040
4294966784
4294966272
4294965248
4294963200
4294959104
4294950912
4294934528
4294901760
4294836224
4294705152
4294443008
4293918720
4292870144
4290772992
4286578688
4278190080
4261412864
4227858432
4160749568
4026531840
3758096384
3221225472
2147483648
0
32
```

as desired :)

Comment: You really discuss this problem clearly. And I thought it arbitrary length in python but didn't realize the it would be smaller and smaller. All the way, thank you!@Magnus Hoff

Comment: @liuxy: If your problem is solved, you should accept the answer that solved it.  You can do that by clicking the greyed-out check mark below its vote count.  That gives a reward for helping you and removes the question from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have "32-bit integers". Its integers are arbitrary (read:infinite) length. This means that -1 is *not* 0xffffffff, but is instead an infinitely long binary sequence of 1s.

Comment: "infinitely long binary sequence of 1s"... well... _conceptually_ it can make sense to think of it that way, and it will work that way in this counter. The internal representation is not infinite ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the 32bit representation limit

```
def countOnes(num):
    num = num % (1 << 32)
    count = 0
    while(num):
        count += 1
        num = num&(num-1)
    return count
```

Comment: No need for the `+ (1 <<32)` here; the `%` reduction is enough.